# Execute Timer Action instantly(and not wait for Timer.interval)[Powershell3]

Tags: powershell-3.0

Currently executing Timer based Actions,activates the action after the specified timer interval.

I want a repeating timer based action but when setting it for longer intervals (eg 1hour) etc ,there has to be a way to test if the action block correctly executes without having to wait for the entire interval.

Is it possible to activate the action instantly and not wait for it to start after Timer.interval?

```
***Console***

 17-08-2020 07:30:18 Script_Started
    
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
4      Timer.Elapsed                   NotStarted    False                                 Write-Host  $n


17-08-2020 07:30:28 Action block executed after Interval = 10000  
17-08-2020 07:30:38 Action block executed after Interval = 10000  



***Script***   
$Timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$objectEventArgs = @{
    InputObject = $Timer
    EventName = 'Elapsed'
    SourceIdentifier = 'Timer.Elapsed'
}

$Timer.Interval = 1000 * 10 
$Timer.Autoreset = $True
$Timer.Enabled = $True


$global:n = "  Action block executed after Interval = " +  $Timer.Interval


Write-Host $((Get-Date).ToString() + "  Script_Started")

$action = { Write-Host  $(Get-Date).ToString() + $n } 

Register-ObjectEvent @objectEventArgs -Action $action


#Unregister-Event  -SourceIdentifier 'Timer.Elapsed'
```

Comment: Why use timer if you do not want a timer based action?

Comment: I do want a repeating timer based action but when setting it for longer intervals (eg 1hour) etc ,there has to be a way to test if the action block correctly executes without having to wait for the entire interval.